# What does Plancherel's (or rather Parseval's actually) formula say for this f?

Tags: fourier-series

Given
$$f(x) = 1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin (nx)}{3^n}$$

what is the easy way to find out the following equation's answer is odd or even?

- $$\begin{align*}
  &\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)\,dx\\  
  &\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)\cos(3x)\,dx\\ 
  &\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)\sin(5x)\,dx
  \end{align*}$$

1) =a_0/2=1/2 odd

2) =0  no cosine terms

3) =1/3^5 =1/243 odd

Sum of odd function is odd

How to calculate following f by using Plancherel's Theorem? or Parseval's theorem?
$$\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f\bigl(x^2\bigr)\,dx.$$

this is also given with the question as a Hint- (geometric series formula ∑r^n= r/(1-r), if (r|<1.))

To calculate this by plancherel or Parseval's theorem are we going to use the given function?

Comment: Please think a bit and give an *informative* title, don't just repeat the instructions you are given (namely, to come up with a specific, informative title!). Please don't just copy your assignment here. Please provide context.

Comment: The tag (differential-equations) might be misleading, I think (Fourier-series) might be better.

Comment: What's your math question? be specific.

Comment: In the last integral I believe there should be $f(x)^2$ instead of $f(x^2)$...

Comment: @Argon A function is given, and some values are to be calculated.

Comment: @AD.: The original read: `(1/π) ∫_(-π)^π f((x)^2)dx `; so the OP certainly wrote $f(x^2)$; whether he *meant* it to be  $f(x)^2$... well, somehow I suspect we may never know.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thanks, I would guess it was a typo :)

Comment: @AD. The title used to be "What's your math question? be specific".  It was changed.

Comment: 1. First part was just to find the answers are odd or even etc.i think . So when i try to solve the 2) 2nd part of problem . all i see is "use Plancherel's Theorem to calculate  (1/π) ∫_(-π)^π f(x)^2dx So i guess we going to use the given function to solve this problem?

Comment: @andy_Wiz In your comment you say $f(x)^2$ but in the post it is $f(x^2)$ (in which case there is no direct connection to the Plancherel/Parseval thm).

Answer (score 2):

**Hints:**

1. What does even or odd mean? Can you simplify $f(-x)$? Try! (*Edit:* The function $f$ of the post has changed and the answer too - now look at $f(-x)$ for $x$ close to 0).
2. How do you calculate Fourier coefficients? These are all Fourier coefficients (you might wish to use the Weierstrass M-test in order to justify interchange summation and integration).
3. What does Plancherel's (or rather [Parseval](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_theorem)'s actually) formula say for this $f$?
   (You will end up summing a geometric series.)

---

I hope you manage to walk through the problems now...